# vue-router: Optional fixed + path parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to have one route object for the following scenarios:

- `/a/123/b`
- `/b`

What I have tried, is:

{
    path: '(a/:a)?/b',
    ...
}

This seems to work when testing the path on the [Express route tester](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/), but only for `path-to-regexp` version 0.1.7. Any version above that will escape special characters.

In what way is this possible with the new version of `path-to-regexp` that `vue-router` uses?

Comment: Express Router and Vue Router both are a different entity.

Comment: They both use https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp according to the docs. I added the Express route tester example to illustrate the change in behavior in the different `path-to-regexp` versions.

Answer (score 4):

Express Router and Vue Router are different, but if what you mean is you want to create a route with dynamic url, then perhaps you can use named routes from https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

For example:

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '(a/:a)?/b',
      name: 'a',
      component: SomeComponent
    }
  ]
})
```

Then your navigation to SomeComponent should have something like:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'a', params: { a: 123 }}">SomeComponent</router-link>
```

Comment: Of course they are different, but under the hood they both use `path-to-regexp` https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp. I added the Express route tester example to illustrate that what you are suggesting does work for `path-to-regexp`@0.1.7, but not for >=1.0, which is what vue-router is using. As mentioned in my question, I have tried the answer in your suggestion, but because the newest version of `path-to-regexp` encodes special characters, it does not work.